# Can anybody help me to expand these file to specified folder? (.batch)

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd

I want to expand some files in folder to another folder.
Following command line works for me:

```
 expand C:\Driver\newfolder\*.* C:\Temp\otherfolder\
```

How can I run it into batch script?

Comment: Are you getting an error? There's nothing in that command that would have to be altered to be made into a batch script. It should be working.

Comment: Please add more details to your question!

Answer (score 0):

You just copy & paste that line into notepad, then hit save as --> all file types and name it DUH.bat or DUH.cmd (I prefer .bat) and change duh to the name of the file.